# Option to open mobile link in browser or in app

Tags: android, ios

Good day!  am trying to find out how to configure a mobile link to give the user the option to open the link either in Facebook's mobile site or in the FB mobile application

Thanks in advance for your input and support!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer is here:
https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/index.html
Have a nice day